# Updated to v. 2.8; Why, now, all animations work except one in v. 2.79 .blend?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I made an animated scene with Blender version 2.79 and then updated to 2.8.
 The animations for my cameras and second character work just fine. But, for some reason, the first character is not animating at all. The keyframes are still there. 
 Am I missing some setting that's preventing the animation of the first character? Perhaps I have to retro-date to v. 2.79 to save the .blend in an alternate state, perhaps, with no objects selected, then try again in v. 2.8. Hopefully, there's an easier fix.

Comment: Don't jump versions

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by unparenting the character from the ground plane object. The configuration worked in 2.79 but not in 2.8 for some reason. Oh well, easy fix.